# pass variable from UIViewController to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a class file for my UIView(draw2D) and ViewController(ViewControllerImage)

When the view loads, viewControllerImage receives a pushed variable. That works, I now need to assign the variable into the draw2D.

draw2D.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) double thicknessValue2;
```

How do I access that inside the ViewController inside the viewDidLoad to set a variable inside the draw2D?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass double to Viewcontroller then to UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056991/pass-double-to-viewcontroller-then-to-uiview)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your `draw2D` view is a property/subview of your `ViewControllerImage` view?

The setter for this property can be used in one of 2 ways:

```
myDraw2D.thicknessValue2 = whatever;
```

or

```
[myDraw2D setThicknessValue2:whatever];
```

Comment: draw2D is a UIView and is inside the UIViewController if that's what you mean? but when I try this 
    `draw2D.thicknessValue2 = self.thicknessValue1;` i get the error "is not a property of object type" What I need to do is create an object for the UIView `I assume` but that's where I'm struggling

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate `draw2D` (UIView) inside `viewControllerImage` (UIViewContoller) and acces it property.

e.g.,

```
UIView *someView= (UIView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nameOfXIB" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

[self.view addSubView:someView];

someView.thicknessValue2 = YourPushedValue;
```

Don't forget to `@synthesize` your `thicknessValue2` in `.m` file.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is very confusing to me, sorry for my lack of knowledge. So I have the viewController with the passed variable (double) I now need to pass that to the UIView (draw2D) that is the UIView of the UIViewController. So I have ViewControllerImage and draw2D. in the draw2D.h I have the @property for the variable to be received. in the viewControllerImage.m in the viewDidLoad, I would use the code you provided there? and in the draw2D.m I would synthesize the thicknessValue2?

Comment: Really, @synthesize? That hasn't been necessary for some time now, and it's best not to do it any more (unless necessary, like when you override both the setter and getter).

Comment: @rdelmar, I know it is not necessary sometime, but the way i used it, OP might get error due to the missing `@synthesize` and he had to prefix with `_`, not aware about the OP's further details at this point that's why i suggested.